# Cannot use Ruby Math library with Opal

Tags: javascript, ruby, opalrb, opal

Is there a way to use the ruby Math library in Opal ?

I got the following error message `Uncaught NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Math` when using `Math::PI` in my ruby method.

The ruby code :

```
class Numeric
  def degrees
    self * Math::PI / 180 
  end
end
```

The generated javascript by Opal :

```
/* Generated by Opal 0.6.3 */
(function($opal) {
  var self = $opal.top, $scope = $opal, nil = $opal.nil, $breaker = $opal.breaker, $slice = $opal.slice, $klass = $opal.klass;

  $opal.add_stubs(['$/', '$*']);
  return (function($base, $super) {
    function $Numeric(){};
    var self = $Numeric = $klass($base, $super, 'Numeric', $Numeric);

    var def = self._proto, $scope = self._scope;

    return (def.$degrees = function() {
      var $a, $b, self = this;

      return self['$*']((($a = ((($b = $scope.Math) == null ? $opal.cm('Math') : $b))._scope).PI == null ? $a.cm('PI') : $a.PI))['$/'](180);
    }, nil) && 'degrees'
  })(self, null)
})(Opal);

//# sourceMappingURL=/__opal_source_maps__/game_engine/numeric.js.map
;
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Math` module is in Opal's `stdlib` and isn't included in the default runtime (as far as I can tell).

Depending on your deployment context, it might be easiest to `build` the `Math` module (`Opal::Builder.build('math')`) into a file.

For your specific example, though, you can just use the JS PI approximation (which is all that Opal's `Math::PI` does anyway):

```
class Numeric
  def degrees
    self * `Math.PI` / 180 
  end
end
```

Comment: Great ! I've built it into a file since I use a lot of math functions. Thanks !!

Comment: if anyone needs to build it into a file, here is the code to be run from an irb console : `File.open("math.js", 'w') { |file| file.write(Opal::Builder.build('math')) }`